# Should the server convert incoming data to JSON or client should send data as JSON?

Tags: json, database, rest, backend

For example, I want to send this data to the server:

`{"values": {"key1": "property1", "key2": "property2", "key3": "property3"}}`

This values key is supposed to be saved as JSON string in database. Now, where exactly should this JSON be converted?

I mean should I send data from client side as JSON string like `{"values": "{\"key1\":\"property1\",\"key2\":\"property2\",\"key3\":\"property3\"}"}` or the server should convert it into JSON and save it to the database? Is it somewhat mentioned in REST principles or something?

Comment: If the client doesn’t send JSON, what format would you send the data as? You could use form encoding, XML, or one of a few other content types, but I imagine there isn’t much point. Also, know that this is an opinion question, so once a mod sees it they’ll close it as “off topic”. One thing I’ll say for sure is, however you end up sending the data from the client to the server, make sure you validate the data before storing it. Don’t just store any old JSON that the client sends, just because you know you want to store JSON.

Comment: Well, client would just send plain object I guess. Anyway, I got your point.

Comment: Google “Content-Type Header” and read what you find. Once you understand it, you’ll realize that your question and suggestion makes no sense. (Which is totally okay, you just don’t understand how the HTTP Request communication works yet!)

Comment: Yeah everything makes sense now. That was a dumb question. Thanks for answering.

Comment: It wasn’t a dumb question. You don’t know what you don’t know. I’ve definitely had the problem of not knowing what to Google in order to answer something myself. I knew if I just told you what to search, you’d figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

What format are you wrapping this JSON in? Is it in another JSON object? You might want to consider not doing that and use the 'parent formats' native way to express this object.

The fact that it eventually gets stored as JSON in your database is a detail that your client shouldn't have to care about.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: Also does this mean that client can just send regular object or array and it's server responsibility to transform the request into correct data types? Say json string in this case.

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks.